# Is it appropriate to perform outlier treatment on test sample data set? I am building logistic regression model

Tags: r, logistic, outliers, validation

I am building logistic regression model. Is it ok to perform outlier treatment on significant variables after building the model and if yes, do we need to perform outlier treatment on test sample data as well. ?

Comment: No, generally it's usually not okay. Specifically it might be (you don't provide sufficient background information), but it's probably not.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just clarifying, I have taken train and test data samples from the main dataset and built a logistic regression model using the train sample dataset.. Now if I want to do outlier treatment, Is it ok to do it on the train dataset, if yes, should I treat outliers on the test sample aswell? or is it better to  treat outlier on the main data set itself?

Comment: You should create a model that includes the process that creates these extreme values.